# Merging several xml from a Restfull service and feeding it to Google Maps

Tags: xml, google-maps, rest

I'm trying to get several xml with coordinates from a Restful service and merging them to be able to feed Google Maps pins for a store locator app.

I have been toying with some ideas I found around:

```
$file1 = simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://service.rest.com/portal-rest/countries/45/stores/12217?idLang=2' /*. urlencode('b&c')*/));
$file2 = simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://service.rest.com/portal-rest/countries/74/stores/12217?idLang=2' /*. urlencode('b&c')*/));

function simplexml_merge (SimpleXMLElement &$file1, SimpleXMLElement $file2)
{
// convert SimpleXML objects into DOM ones
$dom1 = new DomDocument();
$dom2 = new DomDocument();
$dom1->loadXML($file1->asXML());
$dom2->loadXML($file2->asXML());

// pull all child elements of second XML
$xpath = new domXPath($dom2);
$xpathQuery = $xpath->query('/*/*');
for ($i = 0; $i < $xpathQuery->length; $i++)
{
// and pump them into first one
$dom1->documentElement->appendChild(
$dom1->importNode($xpathQuery->item($i), true));
}
$file1 = simplexml_import_dom($dom1);
}

$file1 = simplexml_load_string('<root><child>child 1</child></root>');
$file2 = simplexml_load_string('<root><child>child 2</child></root>');
simplexml_merge($file1, $file2);
echo($file1->asXml());
?>
```

But I'm not getting any output apart from "child1 child2". Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example works as expected, the output is:

```
<root><child>child 1</child><child>child 2</child></root>
```

....Take a look at browser->viewsource